# Vue.js: Cannot access data from function / methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am getting value as `undefined` when I try to access `this.perMonth` from `fnTwo()` and `fnThree()` but works in `fnOne()`. I can run a function from `data(){}` and can return some values but cannot return that's in `data(){}` eg.`this.perMonth` (check `fnThree()`)

```js
Vue.component('BuySubscription', {
  template: '#buy-subscription',
  data() {
    return {
      perMonth: 19,
      valFromFnTwo: this.fnTwo(),
      valFromFnThree: this.fnThree()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fnOne() {
      console.log("from fnOne: get data > perMonth: " + this.perMonth);
      return this.perMonth
    },
    fnTwo() {
      console.log("from fnTwo: get data > perMonth : " + this.perMonth);
      return this.perMonth
    },
    fnThree() {
      console.log("from fnThree: get data > perMonth " + this.perMonth);
      console.log("from fnThree: get data > valFromFnTwo: " + this.valFromFnTwo);
      return 123 // retruns static value
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
body { font-family: arial; font-size: 12px}
p {margin: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-center">
  <buy-subscription></buy-subscription>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="buy-subscription">
  <div>
    <p>value from data > perMonth: {{perMonth}}</p>
    <p>value from data > valFromFnTwo:  {{valFromFnTwo}} <span style="color: red"> <-- getting Undefined here (see console)</span></p>
    <p>value from fnOne(): {{fnOne()}}</p>
    <p>value from fnTwo(): {{fnTwo()}}</p>
    <p>value from fnThree(): {{fnThree()}}</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

Also, please consider if I have nested array of data which I like to process:

```
  data() {
    return {
      perMonth: 19,
      someVarViaFns: [
        {
          valFromFnTwo: this.fnTwo(1),
          valFromFnThree: this.fnThree(2) 
        },        
        {
          valFromFnTwo: this.fnTwo(5),
          valFromFnThree: this.fnThree(9) 
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can use computed properties: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling the Vue instance's methods from within the `data` method is problematic because the data properties have not been set yet. So, any references to data properties in those methods (`this.perMonth` in your case) will return `undefined` .

Set the values of `valFromFnTwo` and `valFromFnThree` in the `created` or `mounted` hook instead. These hooks fire after the `data` method has returned, so references to data properties will work as expected.

```
data() {
  return {
    perMonth: 19,
    valFromFnTwo: null,
    valFromFnThree: null
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.valFromFnTwo = this.fnTwo();
  this.valFromFnThree = this.fnThree();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. What you defined above seem to be good solution for now, but what if there is nested array of data?

Comment: You can just set that in the mounted hook as well. `this.someVarViaFns = [{ valFromFnTwo: this.fnTwo(1), ... }, { ... }]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having this issue because of the [Hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) behavior of the JS Engine.

Instead of declaring it in your data use computed properties:

```
computed: {
  fnTwo() {
    // you can do other operations here also
    // the currency variables is just an example. not mandatory
    let currency = 'usd';

    return "value from fnTwo: " + this.perMonth + ' ' + currency;
  }
}
```

Then you can render it in your template `<p>{{ fnTwo }}</p>` or even `<p>{{ fnTwo()</p>` both should work.

Comment: This would make the property reactive to changes of `this.perMonth`, which might not be what OP wants.